# Video full screen in a Scroll view

Tags: react-native

I have multiple video elements in a scroll view and i want to toggle a video full screen when double tapped, i used react-native-gesture-handler to listen for the double tap event how ever the video element just won't switch to full screen (stays inside it's enclosing component) instead only the app does (the status bar goes away)

```
<GestureHandlerRootView style={tw`rounded-lg overflow-hidden`}>
  <TapGestureHandler
    onHandlerStateChange={({nativeEvent}) => {
      nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE && onPress();
    }}
    waitFor={doubleTap}>
    <TapGestureHandler
      ref={doubleTap}
      onHandlerStateChange={({nativeEvent}) => {
        if (nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
          toggleFullScreen();
        }
      }}
      numberOfTaps={2}>
        ...
        <Video
          source={{uri: section.src}}
          style={videoStyle}
          paused={!isPlaying}
          fullscreen={isFullScreen}
          fullscreenOrientation="landscape"
          fullscreenAutorotate
          muted
          repeat
        />
```

tried using a ref to the video and:  videoRef.current.presentFullscreenPlayer();
got the same behavior